# newbie question about css property set up in Web developer 2010 Express

Tags: css, model-view-controller

I am relatively new in C# and ASP.NET MVC.

There is something unusual that happens and it could be a simple property setup...

I have a MVC Web app and a css file associated with it in my Content folder.
Now everytime I do some changes in the css file I don't see these changes when I run the app. It seems that whatever I do the app keeps on using the old file. I can see it when I do a View Source on the page.

I played a bit with the Copy to Output Directory property in Web Developer without any good results.

Am I really missing something here ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either restart casini, the web server for asp.net, the icon down by the clock or try hitting F5 in the browser a bunch of times.

Comment: "As my old grandmother used to say, 'Anything mechanical, just give it a good bash'" *BASH* "Try it now." ... (The Longest Day, in case anyone is wondering: http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0056197/ )

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing the cache in your browser.